# Proof of differentiability of $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f$ be a function defined on the interval $(-1,1)$ such that for all $x,y\in(-1,1)$,

$f(x+y)=\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{1-f(x)f(y)}$.

Suppose that $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$.

Show that $f$ is differentiable on $(-1,1)$.

For me I can see that $\tan(x)$ is obviously a case of $f$, but I cannot find a general proof for this $f$. Could any kind soul help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all notice that $f(0)$ satisfies the equation $f(0)=\frac{2f(0)}{1-f^2(0)}$, so $f(0)=0$. 
The function $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$, so the limit $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(h)}{h}=f'(0)$ exists. Now fix an $x\in (-1,1)$ and compute the fraction $\frac{f(x+h)-f(h)}{h}$ using the identity you know for $f(x+h)$. After a few calculations, the quantity $\tfrac{f(h)}{h}$ appears, multiplied by a constant. You then take the limit as $h\rightarrow 0$.